# Install XP over Ubuntu. (Flash Drive)

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

My girlfriend needs to install Windows XP over Ubuntu on her PC, because she need to run some software that Wine and a visual machine can't handle as well as the 'real' thing.

Problem is, it seems very difficult to make a bootable flash drive with the files from a XP .iso from Ubuntu.

All the guides I could find was about Windows 7, formatting the USB as NTFS, then use UNetbootin to extract the files to the USB.

Problem is, that only works with 7, not XP. Does anyone know how I can make a bootable XP flash drive? Thanks!

It's really important.

Comment: It's really hard to get XP to work on a USB. There's a way to do it with bartPE though, I've never gotten it to work.

Comment: Try using WINE to run UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example ;). Or you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and add your CD/DVD drive to the Virtual Mashine. Then you can install XP.

http://www.tuxarena.com/static/tut_iso_ubuntu.php

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is making an XP bootable USB, which I've found to be nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can install BartPE to boot from a USB stick, but this is not what you want.  BartPE is a Preinstallation environment, and you must have all the software you want to use already set up within BartPE beforehand.  It isn't like a regular OS... it is a LiveCD environment.

You *can* install XP to run from an external USB hard drive, which means you can install it to run from a USB flash drive.  The instructions are detailed and quite complex.
[This is an EHow article on it.](http://www.ehow.com/how_4853554_install-xp-external-hard-drive.html)

Some people simply connected the external USB device to the computer, booted to the XP installation disc, and their external drive was detected by the XP installation setup as a viable device to install to.  They installed to that external device, and everything worked out hunky dory.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

also if you some how handle to get XP installed to the Stick it won't work cause XP needs to be on drive C, but C is always asigned to the first harddrive on the pc. You see the Problem.

I think the solution is to shrink the size of your linux/ubuntu. And install XP native on the free space (dual boot).